# How to Fix java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Tags: android, type-conversion

I am creating an android application that consists of registration form in dialog. Here, I placed a drop down spinner in registration dialog. But,here it was showing type casting error even i did the correct type casting. Please check it and make it solve. I am trying to solve since 2 hours. This is my code:
package com.example.testingsample;

```
import com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    Button checking,spinner_check;
    EditText username,password,confirm,seq_answer;
    ButtonFlat clear,register;
    Spinner spinner;

    String[] questions = {
            "What is your first name.?",
            "What is your first pet name.?",
            "What is your school name.?",
            "What is your date of birth.?",
            };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        checking = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        checking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                android.app.Dialog registration_dialog = new android.app.Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                registration_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.signup);
                registration_dialog.setTitle("MedeQuip Registration");
                username = (EditText)registration_dialog.findViewById(R.id.Dialog_edittext_username);
                password = (EditText)registration_dialog.findViewById(R.id.Dialog_edittext_password);
                confirm = (EditText)registration_dialog.findViewById(R.id.Dialog_edittext_confirmpassword);


                spinner = (Spinner)registration_dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                ArrayAdapter adpter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this ,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,questions);
                spinner.setAdapter(adpter);
                spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                            View view, int position, long id) 
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, questions[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                }); 
                seq_answer = (EditText)registration_dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                clear = (ButtonFlat)registration_dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_clear);
                register = (ButtonFlat)registration_dialog.findViewById(R.id.Dialog_button_register);
                //seq_answer = (EditText)registration_dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1);*/
                /*spinner_check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Checking", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }   

                });*/
                registration_dialog.show();



            }
            });



    }}
```

This is my dialog xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Dialog_edittext_password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Dialog_edittext_username"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Dialog_edittext_confirmpassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Dialog_edittext_password"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Confirm Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Dialog_edittext_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="User Name" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="345dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Dialog_edittext_confirmpassword"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
        android:id="@+id/Dialog_button_register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dialog_button_clear"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" >
    </com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat>

    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat
        android:id="@+id/dialog_button_clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginRight="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Dialog_button_register"
        android:text="clear"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" >
    </com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFlat>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your answer for security question" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Its look good. Clean your project and run it again.

Comment: try cleaning your proj

Comment: Its working dude after cleaning project. Can u tell me how it was done.? @AnirudhSharma

Comment: @lakshman some times wrong references are made in the r file and cleaning helps in correcting those.

Comment: Thank u dude by clearing this and thanks for the quick reply @AnirudhSharma and Mukesh Kumar

Comment: @lakshman no prob :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem i faced but i solved that problem with following solutions

-> If you are implementing in Eclipse once clean the project then test it.

-> If above also not works once restart your Eclipse.

Hope it will helps you.